# Let $f(x)=(x+1)^2-1,~x\ge -1$. Then find the set $\{x:~f(x)=f^{-1}(x)\}$

Tags: functions

Options (More than one)

1. 0
2. -1
3. $\frac{-3\pm i\sqrt 3}{2}$
4. 1

Let $$y=(x+1)^2-1$$
$$\sqrt{y+1}-1=x$$

$$f^{-1}x=\sqrt{x+1}-1$$

So

$$\sqrt{x+1}=(x+1)^2$$

Hence $0,-1$ fit

Also plugging in $\frac{-3+i\sqrt 3}{2}$ gives

$$\sqrt {\omega} =\omega^2$$ where $\omega$ is complex cube root of unity, and hence the equation is also satisfied

So the answer the answer should be options 1,2,3; but only 1,2 are correct according to the answer. What am I going wrong?

Comment: In the definition of the question it is asserted : $x\geq -1$ which implicitly assumes that $x$ is real (and even if you read it as Re$(x)\geq -1$ it still excludes the complex solutions)

Comment: @H. H. Rugh, wait so, if there was no condition, the function is not a bijection and hence its inverse won't be a function (on y) anymore, but it still is a polynomial, of degree two, so why does it have 3 roots?

Comment: @user675453 Not sure what you mean? When $x\geq -1$ we are looking for the roots of $f(f(x))=x$ which as a polynomial equation of degre 4 has the four roots indicated by the cases 1.,2. and 3. above. The question was why case 3. is excluded. And this is because of the restriction on the domain.

Comment: @H. H. Rugh, Degree 4? Oh, yeah. I mistakenly thought $f^{-1}(f(x))=x$

Comment: If the function f is invertible and strictly ascending then the equation $f(x) = f^{-1}(x)$ is equivalent to the equation$ f(x) = x$.